# installed Node.js but npm module not found error

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, command-line-interface, npm-install

I downloaded node.js from nodejs.org ,today i tried to check my npm version(from cmd prompt /windows power shell/ vs code) but it was giving me same error but when i tried it from node.js cmd prompt it works fine i wanted to resolve error in vs code and cmd

[Error shown in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyjLm.png)

[Error shown in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBtEg.png)

[node.js cmd prompt (here it works)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JhOx.png)

I thought that there may be some problem in path I tried several path but nothing changed

[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCQpb.png)

Comment: Did u try restarting your system?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please prefer post code in place of image : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the problem with your path.

Try deleting this path -- `C:\Users\sande\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm`

Also, try restarting your PC.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install nvm and it solved my problem there may be error because of space in my username

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).